# Split String using C++

Tags: c++, string, split

I am having problems splitting a string using pure C++

The string always looks like this

```
12344//1238
```

First int then // and then the second int.

Need help to get the two int values and ignore the //

Comment: What kind of problems? You might want to look at the first related link to the right.

Comment: I dont know how to split the string to get the two int and ignore the //

Comment: what are you trying to do with the string? any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string org = "12344//1238";

size_t p = org.find("//");
string str2 = org.substr(0,p);
string str3 = org.substr(p+2,org.size());

cout << str2 << " "<< str3;
```

Comment: Seems better to define the separator as a string. Then do `p+sep.size()` instead of the (brittle) `p+2`.

Comment: Thanks that worked very well! It did the trick!!!!

Comment: @Madbreaks I did that because OP said the string is always in that format. Just to keep things simple.

Answer (score 1):

why cant we use sscanf?

```
char os[20]={"12344//1238"};
int a,b;
sscanf(os,"%d//%d",a,b);
```

[Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) function

Comment: I don't mind getting downvoted, but please speak up as to why

Comment: It may be more C than C++, and may not be thread-safe, but it *does* split strings.

Comment: Thanks @chris, I agree more standard C.  But since C++ is a superset of C, it's perfectly legal to use.

Answer (score 0):

This should Split and convert to integers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

class BadConversion : public std::runtime_error {
public:
  BadConversion(std::string const& s)
    : std::runtime_error(s)
    { }
};

inline double convertToInt(std::string const& s,
                              bool failIfLeftoverChars = true)
{
  std::istringstream i(s);
  int x;
  char c;
  if (!(i >> x) || (failIfLeftoverChars && i.get(c)))
    throw BadConversion("convertToInt(\"" + s + "\")");
  return x;
}

int main()
{
    std::string pieces = "12344//1238";

    unsigned pos;
    pos = pieces.find("//");
    std::string first = pieces.substr(0, pos);
    std::string second = pieces.substr(pos + 2);
    std::cout << "first: " << first << " second " << second << std::endl;
    double d1 = convertToInt(first), d2 = convertToInt(second) ;
    std::cout << d1 << " " << d2 << std::endl ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can think of:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main ()
{
 int int1, int2;
 char slash1, slash2;

 //HERE IT IS:
 stringstream os ("12344//1238");
 os>> int1 >> slash1 >> slash2 >> int2;
 //You may want to verify that slash1 and slash2 really are /'s

 cout << "I just read in " << int1 << " and " << int2 << ".\n";

 system ("pause");
}
```

Also nice because it's so easy to rewrite -- if, say, you decide to read in ints delimited by something else.

Answer (score 0):

Take the integers in as a string. 
The string will then have the numbers and the // symbols.
Next you can run a simple for loop looking for the '/' in the string.
The values prior to the symbol are stored in another string. 
When '/' appears, the for loop will terminate. You now have the index of the first
'/' symbol.
Increment the index and copy the rest of the string  using anothe for loop, in another
string.
Now you have two separate strings.